# How do you set a signed cookie in a Rails integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiondispatch

How do you set a signed cookie within a Rails integration test?

For example, assuming I load the :user_id from the cookie, this is the way I would expect to test it, but no joy:

```
  test "success when cookie properly set" do
    cookies.signed[:user_id] = @user.id
    get user_url(@user)
    assert_response :success
  end
```

I understand that its testing the implementation, but in some cases its necessary.

**Update: Works But Ugly**

I have a work around, but its pretty ugly. This passes the cookie as a header to the get request and requires that you manually sign the and format the cookie:

```
  test "success when cookie properly set" do
    signed_user_id="eyJfcmFpb..."
    get user_url(@user), headers: { "HTTP_COOKIE" => "user_id=#{ signed_user_id }" }
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Comment: `cookies` is plain `Rack::Test::CookieJar`, i'm not sure how to do that before the request, but after you have a request to work with `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.build(request, cookies.to_hash).signed[:user_id] = id`

Comment: @Alex yeah the request object doesn't exist yet. I tried making a request first, but even in that case it wouldn't modify the cookie for the next request.